# How to install squid-deb-proxy-client via preseed/early_command

Tags: proxy, squid, preseed

Using Lucid, installing from the Lucid mini.iso.  Both AMD64.

In the following I've tried as \, all of apt-get, apt-install, anna-install, dpkg:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string <cmd+opt> squid-deb-proxy-client
```

I've also tried:

```
d-i preseed/early_command string /usr/bin/wget \
    -O squid-deb-proxy-client_0.3.1_all.deb \
    http://ubuntu.media.mit.edu/ubuntu//pool/universe/s/squid-deb-proxy/squid-deb-proxy-client_0.3.1_all.deb && dpkg -i squid-deb-proxy-client_0.3.1_all.deb
```

Is this possible, and if nor what is the earliest point one can get a installation to use the squid-deb-proxy server?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this via "d-i pkgsel/include"?

Comment: No. that is what I have now.  I was just wondering if it is possible to get this set up as early as possible.  Does using `d-i pkgsel/include ....` mean that all package downloads will go though the proxy?

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding you correctly, if all you want is your downloads to go through a proxy, you should use "d-i mirror/http/proxy string".  If you want it to go through a proxy on the same box you're installing, that would be much more difficult, but I don't understand why you'd want to do that in the first place.

Comment: Pete the box is actually a VM which boots itself several times _and_ has several children (which boot themselves several times too)  all do an apt update several times.  The idea was to have all these VM's only grab the packages _once_.

Comment: @PeteAshdown you're misunderstanding that it's about the convenience of not having to know the proxy's URL.

Answer (score 4):

To force the installer to use your proxy server, configure it using preseeding properly using the `d-i mirror/http/proxy` option, e.g.:

```
d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://ip-or-hostname-of-proxy:8000/
```

You don't really need the `squid-deb-proxy-client` package to use the Squid proxy. The only purpose of the `-client` package is that it can auto-discover the proxy servers in the network.

Answer (score 3):

When the early_command runs, I don't think you even have `/target` already formatted/mounted. For instance, `preseed/early_command` can be used to install udebs (but note, not standard debs) in the installer environment:

```
# This first command is run as early as possible, just after
# preseeding is read.
#d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install some-udeb
```

You can run this in your late_command, that's when you can actually install stuff in the target system:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target apt-get install -y --force-yes openssh-server; \
true
```

I think the best way to have your system get packages from a proxy is what Pete Ashdown suggested.

Comment: "I think the best way to have your system get packages from a proxy is what Pete Ashdown suggested." the problem is that it's not as convenient because you have to know the proxy's URL. With the squid-deb-proxy-client package, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible due to bug #[1183326](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid-deb-proxy/+bug/1183326), however if one day it gets fixed it should be possible with:

```
d-i anna/choose_modules string squid-deb-proxy-client-udeb
```

In your preseed file, the **d-i mirror/http/proxy** trick will work on limited escenarios due to bug #[642159](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642159)

Comment: why `choose_modules`?  I would expect that it's necessary to tell it where to get the modules from, e.g. to `anna-install /path/to/udeb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post install bash script to install packages, below is the preseed/late_command:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
    cp /cdrom/post_install.sh /target/root/; \
    chroot /target chmod +x /root/post_install.sh; \
    chroot /target bash /root/post_install.sh
```

post_install.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    git \
    python-pip \
    ansible
```