# How to convert a deb package to udeb

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy, deb, debian-installer

Following up on [How to install squid-deb-proxy-client via preseed/early_command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41006/how-to-install-squid-deb-proxy-client-via-preseed-early-command/),  I want to have a udeb of the `squid-deb-proxy-client` package. From reading the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/udeb) it seems it should be easy to convert a regular deb to a udeb.  However, I couldn't find any tool that does it for me.

Because I assume I also need to convert the dependencies to udebs, I wouldn't want to do it manually, so my question is:

How to conveniently convert regular deb packages to udebs?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should `extract` the contents of the `file.deb` using `dpkg -x` and `dpkg -e`.

Then you should create the `file.udeb` using `debhelper`.

`Debhelper` knows the special properties of the `file.udeb` and will do the right thing by default at build time.

**Edited June-01-2016:**

Dpkg-deb is Debian package archive (.deb) manipulation tool.

```
dpkg-deb -x, --extract archive directory
```

Extracts  the  filesystem  tree  from a package archive into the
specified directory.

Use dpkg-deb -x to extract the files from a foo.deb package as shown below:

```
dpkg-deb -x foo.deb /some-dir/debian
ls /some-dir/debian
foo
```

Debhelper is used to help you build a Debian package.

Provide a collection easily understood tools that are 
used in debian/rules to automate various common aspects 
of building a package.

A typical debian/rules file that uses debhelper will call
several debhelper commands in sequence.

Examples of rules files that use debhelper are in:
/usr/share/doc/debhelper/examples/

To create a new Debian package using debhelper, you can just 
copy one of the sample rules files and edit it by hand.

By default, all debhelper programs assume that the temporary
directory used for assembling the tree of files in a package 
is /some-dir/debian/package.

To create a udeb with debhelper, add "Package-Type: udeb" 
to the package's stanza in debian/control.

Debhelper will try to create udebs that comply with debian-installer
policy, by making the generated package files end in .udeb, not
installing any documentation into a udeb, skipping over preinst,
postrm, prerm, and config scripts, etc.

[Source](http://man.he.net/man7/debhelper)

Comment: looks promising. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: It is desirable that you read here: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html and here https://www.strangeparty.com/2010/06/17/a-debian-packaging-howto/ and here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man7/debhelper.7.html

Comment: I don't consider your answer useful for now. Let me explain why. 
"First, you should extract the contents of the file.deb using dpkg -x and dpkg -e" is already good, but it wouldn't hurt to show a command line run of how exactly to use the dpkg tool. 
"Then you should create the file.udeb using debhelper." is a good start, but again, the reader is left alone with figuring out how to actually do it which is the actual question here. Also, "*the* file.udeb" sounds like a specific thing that I should know of, but you don't explain it.

Comment: @Frederick Nord: answer edited.